# Submit button grayed out until check box ticked?

Tags: jquery, html, validation, checkbox

I'm trying to figure out how to gray out the submit button while the check box is un-ticked? Can anybody steer me in the correct direction.

html:

```
<div class = "form-group" id="myform">      
                <div class="checkbox">
                <label>
                    <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox"> I confirm that I am over 18 years of age
                </label>
            </div>
            <br><br>
            <div class ="row">
            <div class ="col-sm-6">
            <input type="submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-block btn-default" value="Submit">
            </div><div class ="col-sm-6">
            <input type="reset" class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-default" value="Clear the Info">
            </div></div>
            <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
            </div>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {


$('#username').focus(); 
$('form').h5Validate({errorClass:'validationError' });

$('#submit').attr('disabled',true);
$('#checkbox').click(function(){
    $('#submit').attr('disabled',!this.checked);
});
$('#myform').submit(function(){
    return $('#checkbox').attr('checked');
});

});
```

Comment: Use `.prop()` instead of `.attr()` for boolean property values

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not this in the click event ?

```
$(document).ready(function() {


    $('#submit').prop('disabled', true); // disabled by default

    $('#checkbox').click(function() {
       // change on checkbox click
       $('#submit').prop('disabled', !$('#checkbox').prop('checked'));
    });

});
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply, the submit button now becomes grayed out by default, but is not conditional on whether the check box is ticked? As in it stays grayed out whether I tick the check box or not

Comment: hello. please check the edit I made. Does it correct your case ?

Answer (score 1):

Hi Pls try this,

```
if($("#checkkBoxId").attr("checked"))
{
    alert("Checked");
     $('#submit').attr('disabled','false');
}
else
{
    alert("Unchecked");
    $('#submit').attr('disabled','true');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#myform').on('change', ':checkbox', function() {
      If($(this).is(':checked')) {
           $(this).closest('#myform').find('#submit').attr('disabled', false);
      } 
      else{
            $(this).closest('#myform').find('#submit').attr('disabled', true);
 });
```